# filter a column with a multiple keywords, in django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to filter a column in DB with a multiple keywords but having a problem. When I try to apply `__contains=` on an array it's doesn't work.

```
def get_tasks_by_filters(request):
    datas = json.loads(request.body)

    tasks = Task.objects.filter(task_name__contains=datas["keywords"])
    serializer = TasksPricesSerializers(tasks, many=True)

    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

And `__contains=` of course working with a single value `Task.objects.filter(task_name__contains=datas["keywords"][0])` But how can apply `__contains=` on multiple keywords/array. What is the possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this using [**`Q()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = Q()

for k in datas["keywords"]:
    query |= Q(task_name__contains=k)

tasks = Task.objects.filter(query)
```